# What is LastQuickScanSource when running get-MpComputerStatus

Tags: powershell, windows-defender

As the title states, does anyone know what the `LastQuickScanSource` parameter of `get-MpComputerStatus` command is? and what do the values mean (i.e. when I run the command I see a "2" value next to LastQuickScanSource)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Last quick scan source relates to what last executed the quick scan

```
0 = scan didn't run 
1 = user initiated 
2 = system initiated
```

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/security/threat-protection/microsoft-defender-antivirus/troubleshoot-microsoft-defender-antivirus

Comment: thank you for the link, this document definitely explains it.